# jQuery UI screen.width dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, screen

How to set dialog `screen.width` exactly?

I'm add code but not run?

```
$(function() {
if (screen.width <= 480) {
    $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 300 });
} else {
    $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 480 });
}

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `screen.width` use `$(window).width()` as shown.

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
   $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 300 });
  } else {
   $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 480 });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 300 });
} else {
    $( ".mydialog" ).dialog({ title: "Check Availability Cruise", width: 480 });
}

});
```

`width()` is a method so use it like a method.